# Mono.Cecil - Не корректно заменяются ресурсы программы

Tags: c#, mono

Класс для замены ресурсов:

```
namespace EditorRes
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Resources;
    using Mono.Cecil;

    public static class ResourceEx
    {
        private static string CreateResourceFile(byte[] FileData)
        {
            string ResPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "res.resources");
            using (var Writer = new ResourceWriter(ResPath))
            {
                Writer.AddResource("Res", FileData);
                Writer.Generate();
            }
            return ResPath;
        }
        private static string CreateResourceFile(List<byte[]> Files)
        {
            string ResPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "res.resources");
            using (var Writer = new ResourceWriter(ResPath))
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (byte[] ByteArray in Files)
                {
                    Writer.AddResource($"Res{index}", ByteArray);
                }
                Writer.Generate();
            }
            return ResPath;
        }

        private static void ReplaceResource(AssemblyDefinition asmDefinition)
        {
            string ResPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "NewText.txt"); // Путь до нового ресурса
            asmDefinition.MainModule.Resources.RemoveAt(0); // Удаляю старый ресурс
            Console.WriteLine("Delete old resource");
            string ResourceFile = CreateResourceFile(File.ReadAllBytes(ResPath)); // Создаю новый ресурс для добавления
            var EmbeddedRes = new EmbeddedResource("ResExtractor.Properties.Resources.resources‎", ManifestResourceAttributes.Public, File.ReadAllBytes(ResourceFile));
            asmDefinition.MainModule.Resources.Add(EmbeddedRes); // Добавляю файл ресурсов
            Console.WriteLine("Add new resource");
            File.Delete(ResourceFile); // Удаляю файл ресурсов
            Console.WriteLine("Delete temp resource");
        }

        public static void SaveNewBuild()
        {
            string stubfile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "ResExtractor.exe");
            string newbuild = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "New_ResExtractor.exe");

            // Читаю сборку
            Console.WriteLine("Read Assembly");
            using (var read = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(stubfile))
            {
                ReplaceResource(read); // Изменяю ресурс
                using (AssemblyDefinition ass = read)
                {
                    Console.Write("Write new build ...");
                    ass.Write(newbuild); // Перезаписываю в новый файл
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
namespace EditorRes
{
    using System;

    internal static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Resource EditorEx [Tested]";
            ResourceEx.SaveNewBuild();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Файл ресурсов оригинального файла:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И файл ресурсов после замены:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Что нужно изменить/добавить чтобы корректно файл отображался?!
Тестовый проект: [ResourceEditor](https://mega.nz/file/LbYGBJYR#Dh32y-fB_xoDDwqIHnYYLBkQMacioiWGpKUkD1aqtjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я смог добавить решение проблемы по замене ресурсов таким способом:

---

```
namespace EditorRes
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Resources;
    using Mono.Cecil;

    public static class ResourceEx
    {
        private static byte[] CreateByteResourceFileInMemory(string FileData) 
        {
            // Создаю новый ресурс в памяти
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (IResourceWriter Writer = new ResourceWriter(ms))
                {
                    Writer.AddResource("Res", FileData);
                    Writer.Generate();
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        private static string CreateStringResourceToFile(byte[] FileData) 
        {
            // Создаю новый ресурс в файле
            string ResPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "res.resources");
            using (IResourceWriter Writer = new ResourceWriter(ResPath))
            {

                Writer.AddResource("Res", FileData);
                Writer.Generate();
            }
            return ResPath;
        }
        private static string CreateResourceFile(List<byte[]> Files)
        {
            string ResPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "res.resources");
            using (var Writer = new ResourceWriter(ResPath))
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (byte[] ByteArray in Files)
                {
                    Writer.AddResource($"Res{index}", ByteArray);
                }
                Writer.Generate();
            }
            return ResPath;
        }

        private static void ReplaceResource(AssemblyDefinition asmDefinition)
        {
            asmDefinition.MainModule.Resources.RemoveAt(0); 
            var ResourceFile = CreateByteResourceFileInMemory(Properties.Resources.NewText);  // File.ReadAllText(ResPath)
            var EmbeddedRes = new EmbeddedResource("ResExtractor.Properties.Resources.resources‎", ManifestResourceAttributes.Public, ResourceFile);
            asmDefinition.MainModule.Resources.Add(EmbeddedRes); 
        }

        public static void SaveNewBuild()
        {
            string stubfile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "ResExtractor.exe");
            string newbuild = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "New_ResExtractor.exe");

            // Читаю сборку
            Console.WriteLine("Read Assembly");
            using (var read = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(stubfile))
            {
                ReplaceResource(read); // Изменяю ресурс
                using (AssemblyDefinition ass = read)
                {
                    Console.Write("Write new build ... ");
                    ass.Write(newbuild); // Перезаписываю в новый файл
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Всё хорошо заменяется, но есть одна проблема:
Я не могу сохранить содержимое файла из ресурсов на рабочий диск ( уже из изменённого `.exe` файла ), создаётся пустой файл, как решить пока не знаю, если кто знает, подскажите!