# C# Resource.ResouceManager

Tags: c#

реализую возможность добавлять в ресурсы приложения картинки (уже скомпилированного).
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом в Properties.Resource я могу узнать есть ли такое уже изображение или нет, дабы предотвратить возможность дубляжа?.
Редактирование выполняю библиотекой Mono.Cecil:

```
public void IsDynamicAssemblyCreatesSuccessfully()
        {
            var asmName = new AssemblyNameDefinition("DynamicAssembly", new Version(1, 0, 0, 0));
            var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.CreateAssembly(asmName, "<Module>", ModuleKind.Dll);
 
            string imageFilePath = @"C:\Users\kalinov\Desktop\20.jpg";
            byte[] imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(imageFilePath);
 
            var imageResource = new EmbeddedResource("SomeImage.jpg", ManifestResourceAttributes.Private, imageData);
            assembly.MainModule.Resources.Add(imageResource);
 
            string desktopDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string assemblyPath = Path.Combine(desktopDirectory, "DynamicAssembly.dll");
 
            assembly.Write(assemblyPath);
        }
```

Comment: В скомпилированном приложении возможно их отредактировать Библиотекой Mono.Cecil.

Comment: Соответственно мне в коде надо проверить есть ли в Resource файл или картинка с таким именем

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1191769/mono-cecil-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B - тут сделали

Comment: Да реализация там есть, но проверки на то что уже есть такой объект там нет )

Comment: хэш сумма не подойдет случайно?

Comment: Я вот что думаю если мы попробуем получить объект if(Resource.ResouceManager.GetObject("2455123") !=null)
Сработает или нет?